# ODBC connection gives Unknown Host error from Power BI

Tags: powerbi, marklogic

I am using an ODBC driver of MarkLogic instance which I am using in Power BI to access MarkLogic database files.

I am using 64 bit ODBC driver and have set up the connection and tested the connection successfully. I have also accessed the MarkLogic files under Documents Database.

But today when I tried to connect from Power BI, it gives me this error:

> Could not translate hostname "myhostname" to address : Unknown host

The same error is thrown when I am trying to test the connection in ODBC set up.
The driver used is Marklogic SQL.

MarkLogic is up and running, and there have been no changes done in any connection properties so far.

Comment: What happens if you `ping myhostname` from the machine you're trying this on?

Comment: Sounds like the PowerBI server is having trouble resolving the IP address. You could look to create local /etc/hosts entries to bypass DNS or bind to the IP just to test connectivity.